# xsl, select a href and create own xml tag

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a html tag like:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

and it want to convert it to:

```
<ownXmlelement adress="http://www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</ownXmlelement>
```

could anyone help me? This doesn´t work :(

```
<xsl:template match="a href">
<ownXmlelement><xsl:value-of select="."/></ownXmlelement>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The output you show is not valid XML syntax.

Comment: yes sorry </ownelement> instead of </ownelement:adress>

Comment: I really believe it should be `<ownXmlelement adress=(...)` or you need an extra attribut. The `<tagname="value">` just isn't xml.

Comment: It's still not right. Please edit your question and post the **exact* result you expect.

Comment: Suggested edit to make the desired output valid XML

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Please don't edit OP code.

Answer (score 0):

The output you show is not valid XML syntax. Perhaps you meant:

```
<ownXmlelement adress="http://www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</ownXmlelement>
```

That would be achieved by:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <ownXmlelement adress="{@href}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </ownXmlelement>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: yes, i meant this output. this solution sounds logic, but it doesn´t work :-(